# How to find corresponding combination Id from a specific combination in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table where the data is like bellow

```
Combination_id      combination
1                    1
1                    3
1                    4
2                    1
2                    3
2                    5
```

I want to find the combination_id based on combination.
Test case

1 . For the combination of 1,3,4 I should get combination id 1

2 . For the combination of 1,3,5 I should get combination id 2

I tried many MySQL queries but failed. Can anyone help me here??

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways, but it depends on how your `combination` is used

For example

```sql
select t1.Combination_id
  from tab1 t1
 where t1.combination in (1,3,4)
 group by t1.Combination_id
 having count(1) = 3
```